# For what values of $k,n$ does the inequality $(4-k)n\ge (2-k)k$ holds?

Tags: inequality

Let $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\le n$ for what values of $k$ and $n$ is

$(4-k)n\ge (2-k)k$ and for what values $(4-k)n < (2-k)k$

if $k=1,2,3,4$ and $n\ge k$ the first inequality holds but for $k\ge 5$ since $0<k-4<k-2$ and $k\le n$ y cannot conclude that $(k-4)n\le (k-2)k$

So I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem. Any suggestion or comment would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $(4-k) n \geq (2-k)k$ we get three cases.

- $k = 4$:  Then the inequality is $0 \geq -8$, which is true regardless of $n$, including all $n \geq k$.
- $0<k<4$: Here, $4-k$ is positive, so we may divide through, yielding $n \geq \frac{k(k-2)}{k-4}$.  There are only three choices for $n$.  If $k = 1$, $n \geq -1/-3 = 1/3$, which is all $n$.  If $k=2$, $n \geq 0/-4 = 0$, which is all $n$.  If $k=3$, $n \geq 3/-1 = -3$, which is all $n$.  So for these few $k$, the inequality holds for all $n$.
- $k>4$:  Here, $4-k$ is negative, so dividing through reverses the sense of the inequality, yielding $n \leq \frac{k(k-2)}{k-4}$.  We know $k \leq n$ and for $k>4$, the gap $\frac{k(k-2)}{k-4} -k = \frac{2k}{k-4} > 2$ and becomes closer to $2$ as $k$ increases.  (Write it as $\frac{2(k-4)+8}{k-4}$ to make this evident.)  This means there is always at least one satisfying choice for $n$ in $\left[k,\frac{k(k-2)}{k-4}\right]$.

By the law of the excluded middle a pair $(k,n)$ satisfies either the first inequality you gave or the second.  Consequently, the $(k,n)$ described above satisfy the first inequality and all other pairs satisfy the second.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you obtain the graph $y = \frac{(2-x) x }{ (4-x)}$ :

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to misleadingly indicate that $(k,n) = (5,16)$ satisfies the first inequality.  It doesn't.

Comment: I meant you should obtain the graph! I didn't say that this is the whole picture!